# Prevent flicker on each page load for Chrome extension that is visible on the page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to have a Chrome extension that provides some extra content in the page in the form of a fixed position div or iframe. I need the extension to stay visible once opened, only closing when the user clicks something to do this.

The simplest API looks like `default_popup`. However this may sit slightly above the page as it's positioned relative to the extension's icon. You could try to nude it down with whitespace but the browser's chrome height could vary for different users so this isn't a reliable solution.

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html",
}
```

[image]

I've tried using a content script to insert a div into the page body:

```
// manifest.json
{
  "name": "Thing",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}

// content.js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.background = 'gold';
div.style.height = '100px';
div.style.width = '100px';
div.style.position = 'fixed';
div.style.top = '0px';
div.style.right = '0px';
div.style.zIndex = '9000000000000000000';
div.frameBorder = 'none';
div.border = '1px solid lightgrey';
div.style.boxShadow = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0px 8px 16px';
div.innerText = 'Small';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

This is working and positioned how I need, however due to the JavaScript reliance the div flickers every time you navigate to a new page. Is there a way around this as it's quite distracting?

Comment: Use [document_start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) and append to document.documentElement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wOxxOm said "Use document_start and append to document.documentElement"

```
// manifest.json
{
  "name": "Thing",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}

// content.js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.background = 'gold';
div.style.height = '100px';
div.style.width = '100px';
div.style.position = 'fixed';
div.style.top = '0px';
div.style.right = '0px';
div.style.zIndex = '9000000000000000000';
div.frameBorder = 'none';
div.border = '1px solid lightgrey';
div.style.boxShadow = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0px 8px 16px';
div.innerText = 'Small';
document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
```